# can we execute different SPs in a stored procedure same time?

Tags: sql-server-2008

In my stored procedure there are 3 stored procedures for three tables.Each  I am passing parameters & stored procedure name from front end(designed in asp.net 4.0)

can we execute that 3 SP's at the same time i.e. parallel execution so that I can minimize stored procedure execution time?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to split up the stored procedure into three separate stored procedures and execute them on three different connections.

It may also be possible, in theory, to write a stored procedure using the CLR in a .Net language and use multithreading to achieve your goal. That option would be more complex. I can't say any more about the second option because I have not actually done it.

See [Multi-threaded code in CLR Stored Procs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1324027/multi-threaded-code-in-clr-stored-procs)